# Range errors when plotting solutions of systems of equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I would like to plot the points $(a,b,c)$ that simultaneously satisfy the equations
$$a^2+b^2=1,\qquad ac+b\frac{1+bc}{a}=0,\qquad c^2+\frac{(1+bc)^2}{a^2}=1.$$

I attempted to do this with `ContourPlot3D` as

```
ContourPlot3D[
     {a^2+b^2,a c+(b(1+b c))/a,c^2+(1+b c)^2/a^2}=={1,0,1},
     {a,-3/2,3/2},
     {b,-3/2,3/2},
     {c,-3/2,3/2}]
```

but *Mathematica* plotted points that had coordinates bigger than 1, which is impossible for these equations.  What can I use to get this plot?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The docs are not absolutely clear on this but I think `ContourPlot3D` can only handle a single scalar equality.

Comment: @george2079  `ContourPlot3D` appears to be able to handle multiple equations, although not in the form used in the Question.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D` seemed to be fine with the form, though I'm not sure how it interpreted it.

Comment: I was going to suggest making a scalar expression, `(a^2+b^2-1)^2+()^2+()^2 ==0`, however there does not appear to be any solution ( or only a single point , or very small region, so contourplot3d doesn't work )

Comment: Ahh.. `Reduce` shows the solution which is just a line. `b==-c==+/-Sqrt[1-a^2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have meant

```
ContourPlot3D[{a^2 + b^2 == 1, a^2 c + (b (1 + b c)) == 0, 
  a^2 c^2 + (1 + b c)^2 == a^2}, {a, -3/2, 3/2}, {b, -3/2, 3/2}, {c, -3/2, 3/2}]
```

which produces

[image]

Basically, I used the edit by David G. Stork, separated the three equations, and multiplied the second and third equations by `a` and `a^2` respectively.

**Addendum**

The intersection of the curves, as requested by the OP in a comment, can be displayed as follows:

```
r = ImplicitRegion[a^2 + b^2 == 1 && a^2 c + (b (1 + b c)) == 0, {a, b, c}];
ring = MeshRegion[DiscretizeRegion[r, {{-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}}], 
  MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Directive[Red, Thickness[.01]], {0, All} -> White}];
ctr = ContourPlot3D[{a^2 + b^2 == 1, a^2 c + (b (1 + b c)) == 0, 
  a^2 c^2 + (1 + b c)^2 == a^2}, {a, -3/2, 3/2}, {b, -3/2, 3/2}, {c, -3/2, 3/2}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.3], Mesh -> None];
Show[{ctr, ring}]
```

[image]

Note that the same plot can be obtained from

```
Solve[{a^2 + b^2 == 1, a^2 c + (b (1 + b c)) == 0, a^2 c^2 + (1 + b c)^2 == a^2}, 
  {a, b, c}]
(* {{a -> -Sqrt[1 - c^2], b -> -c}, {a -> Sqrt[1 - c^2], b -> -c}} *)
Show[{ctr, ParametricPlot3D[{{Sqrt[1 - c^2], -c, c}, {-Sqrt[1 - c^2], -c, c}}, 
  {c, -3/2, 3/2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[.01]]]}]
```

Comment: But that includes points on the boundary of the cube, indicating there are points with coordinates bigger than 1, impossible since each of $a^2,b^2,c^2 < 1$ if it satisfies the equations.

Comment: @JacobBond you should work the word "simultaneously" into the question..

Comment: @JacobBond  Your question appeared to ask for a plot of the three equations.  Instead, do you want a plot of the intersection of the three?  `{{a -> -Sqrt[1 - c^2], b -> -c}, {a -> Sqrt[1 - c^2], b -> -c}}`

Comment: Yes, I intended to ask for points which simultaneously satisfied all threee equations.

Comment: @bbgodfrey So `ParametricPlot3D` parametrized by $c$?

Comment: @JacobBond   Yes, but there undoubtedly is a better way, probably involving the intersection of regions.

Answer (score 1):

We may introduce a variable `d`,then the equations rewrite to a relatively symmetric form

```
a^2 + b^2 == 1, c^2 + d^2 == 1, a*c + b*d == 0, a*d - b*c == 1
```

```
equations = {a^2 + b^2 == 1, c^2 + d^2 == 1, a*c + b*d == 0, a*d - b*c == 1};
sol = Eliminate[equations, d];
Region[ImplicitRegion[sol, {a, b, c}], 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]
```

> `b^2 == 1 - a^2 && c == -b`

[image]

Or

```
ContourPlot3D[{b^2 == 1 - a^2, c == -b}, {a, -1.5, 1.5}, {b, -1.5, 
  1.5}, {c, -1.5, 1.5}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.1], Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Directive[Thick, Red]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**BTW**

We belive that the problem must come from complex since if we set

```
z = a + I*b;
w = c + I*d;
z*Conjugate[w] // ComplexExpand
```

> `a c + b d + I (b c - a d)`

It means that the Hermit product of two complex numbers $z \bar{w}=i$